# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation

Tags: react-native

I'm building a mobile application with React Native, and I have a `ScrollView` inside one of the pages.

The problem is that I have in this page a `FlatList` so when I go to that page, I get this error:
`VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation...` The thing is, I set the `ScrollView` `nestedScrollEnabled` to `true` and I also set the `FlatList's scrollEnabled` to `false` because I don't really need the scroll there (I'm using it to render items from an enum) so I thought that should fix the error, but the error still persist.

It looks like this:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  <MyComponent />
</ScrollView>
```

And `MyComponent` has this FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    scrollEnabled={false}
    style={{padding: 8,marginBottom: 8,}}
    data={categories}
    numColumns={numOfColumns}
    keyExtractor={category => category}
    renderItem={item => renderItem(item.item)}
/>
```

It essentially looks like this:

```
<SafeAreaView>
 <ScrollView>
  <FlatList />
  <OTHER COMPONENTS />
 </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component FlatList and ScrollView have the same orientation(vertical), so you need put your component inside a ScrollView with horizontal orientation like this:

```
<View>
   <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} style={{ width: "100%" }} >
     <View>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
           <MyComponent />
        </ScrollView>
     </View>
   </ScrollView>
 </View>
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is because you are using a FlatList inside a ScrollView.

The FlatList is already a scrollable component,

FlatList are accepting props like `ListHeaderComponent` for rendering header content and `ListFooterComponent` for rendering footer content. Here you can remove the `ScrollView` and instead of that you can only render `FlatList` for making whole page scrollable

You need to change your code as shown below:

```
const _renderHeader = () => <Text>Your Header</Text>
const _renderFooter = () => <Text>Your Footer</Text>
const _renderFooter = () => <Text>FlatList items</Text>

<SafeAreaView>
 <FlatList 
   data={data}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
   renderItem={_renderItem}
   ListHeaderComponent={_renderHeader}
   ListFooterComponent={_renderFooter}
   ListFooterComponentStyle={styles.footerStyle} //If you need to give specific styles for footer component
   ListHeaderComponentStyle={styles.headerStyle} //for header comp style
 />
</SafeAreaView>
```

You don't want to use a ScrollView when you are using a FlatList

[You can check the official docs for more clarification](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent)